# Deploy and run the APK on multiple Android emulators after build using npm script

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk, adb, ionic4

Using [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) we can install the APK and run it but

> if you issue a command without specifying a target device when
>   multiple devices are available, adb generates an error.

so we can use the

`adb devices | tail -n +2 | cut -sf 1 | xargs -I X adb -s X install -r com.myAppPackage`

to install the given app on all connected devices.
Adding alias is as simple as the following:

```
alias installAPK="adb devices | tail -n +2 | cut -sf 1 | xargs -I X adb -s X X install -r $1"
```

But i was wondering how can I deploy and run the APK on multiple Android emulators after it was built using npm?

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json` add the following

```
{
  "scripts":{
      "android-build-dev": "ionic cordova build android --device --prod",
      "android-deploy-to-emulator": "node android.emulator.config.js",
      "android-build-and-deploy-to-emulator": "npm run android-build-dev && npm run android-deploy-to-emulator"
   }
}
```

the `android.emulator.config.js` contains the following

```
const execSync = require("child_process").execSync;

const devicesOutput = execSync("adbn devices", { encoding: "utf-8" });

const deviceIds = devicesOutput.match(/emulator-\d{4}/g);

const execSyncOptions = { encoding: "utf-8", stdio: "inherit" };

deviceIds.forEach((deviceId) => {

      execSync(`adbn -s ${deviceId} install ./platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`, execSyncOptions);

      execSync(`adbn -s ${deviceId} shell am start -n yourappname.app/.MainActivity`);

    });
```